# How to install these Pie Chart controls in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, pie-chart

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442506/Simple-and-Easy-to-Use-Pie-Chart-Controls-in-WPF

Can't seem to get these working in my WPF project. How do I add the references to get going with this pie chart?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign in and download the binaries. You should then unpack the zip file and add a reference (Project->Add Reference->Browse->Browse in Visual Studio) to the downloaded and unpacked `PieControls.dll` file. After you have done this, the following sample code should work.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:pie="clr-namespace:PieControls;assembly=PieControls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <pie:PieChart x:Name="chart1" Width="260" Height="140" PieWidth="120" PieHeight="120"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using PieControls;
...

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<PieSegment> pieCollection = new ObservableCollection<PieSegment>();
        pieCollection.Add(new PieSegment { Color = Colors.Green, Value = 5, Name = "Dogs" });
        pieCollection.Add(new PieSegment { Color = Colors.Yellow, Value = 12, Name = "Cats" });
        pieCollection.Add(new PieSegment { Color = Colors.Red, Value = 20, Name = "Mice" });
        pieCollection.Add(new PieSegment { Color = Colors.DarkCyan, Value = 22, Name = "Lizards" });
        chart1.Data = pieCollection;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Dennis Buntwin: Did you try this or what happened?